# Why size changes while converting list to dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Basically I have list(entire brown corpus).

```
dic1=brown.words()
print 'Total size of Brown Corpus :'
print len(dic1)
```

Output is:

```
Total size of Brown Corpus :
1161192
```

I transformed that list to a dictionary making all values 2 and checked the size.

```
dic=dict((k,2) for k in dic1)
print 'Size of the dict:'
print len(dic)
```

And got this output:

```
Size of the dict:
56057
```

The dictionary contains : `(key:2)`. So if there are 1161192 no of words in list, there should be same amount of entries in the dictionary too. Why does the size change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionaries only store distinct results, so when you convert a list to a dict, you lose any duplicate words.